# plpgsql: raise notice output shows only in pgAdmin

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

postgresql 9.4. I have a function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test(source_ text)
  RETURNS text AS
$BODY$
  DECLARE
  BEGIN
   raise debug '%s', source_;
   return source_ || ' processed';
  END
  $BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql STABLE
  COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION test()
  OWNER TO test;

select * from test('input');
```

I can see notice only from pgAmin, but nothing from ide or toad (and some other) db clients. 
How can I turn on output of "raise notice" or maybe there is other ways to get debug information?

**UPDATE**

I found a workaround: tail -F for a log file and set log_min_messages in postgresql.conf

Comment: `How can I turn on output of "raise notice" ...` But you are not using `raise notice`, you are using `raise debug`.

Comment: ok, that is a mistake. But it can be any message. pgAdmin shows them on tab 'messages', but other clients don't, or I can't find them.

Answer (score 5):

You need to adjust `client_min_messages`, like:

```
set client_min_messages = 'debug';
```

See http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/runtime-config-logging.html#GUC-CLIENT-MIN-MESSAGES for more.

```
test=# create or replace function test() returns int as $$
begin
  raise debug 'foo';
  return 1;
end
$$ language plpgsql immutable;
CREATE FUNCTION
test=# select test();
 test 
------
    1
(1 row)

test=# set client_min_messages = 'debug';
SET
test=# select test();
DEBUG:  foo
 test 
------
    1
(1 row)

test=#
```

Comment: Thanks. that works in psql and needs to execute before every connect. pgAdmin shows messages, but "toad", "navicat" and some other don't even if I set client_min_messages.

Comment: @jNess: well those clients need to _actively_ retrieve messages after a statement has been executed. As this is DBMS specific I assume those multi DBMS tools don't do that.

Comment: Thanks! Working on psql 11!